# Unable to Load an external Swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs6

I am trying to learn Action Script (self study) and therefore I took a project for myself.So this question might be way too simple or idiotic. If it is i apologise.

The goal is simple. I have 2 swf to embed within my swf. when my swf will run, it will load 1st swf by default. when you click a button, it will load the second swf.you can return back to the first swf using a different button.

After researching I came up with the action script mentioned below. The buttons work and the 1st swf work. But the second swf does not load for some reason. No compilation error found (but got an output error "TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.events::Event@2e1785d9 to OpenEvent." but i think that is comming for the working swf because of the xml it is trying to load) . wondering why the second swf is not loading even though I used a similar code as the first and how to rectify it.

url to my swf : http://itnotes.in/RLC/swf/Radio/muses-1.2/radio-tv.swf

my fla file (flash cs6 as3) : [itnotes.in/RLC/swf/Radio/muses-1.2/radio-tv.fla](http://itnotes.in/RLC/swf/Radio/muses-1.2/radio-tv.fla)

Any help deeply appreciated

```
Security.allowDomain("avastarentertainment.com")
Security.allowDomain("itnotes.in")

import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var Xpos:Number = 110;
var Ypos:Number = 180;
var swf:MovieClip;
var loader:Loader=new Loader();
loader.load(new URLRequest('http://itnotes.in/RLC/swf/Radio/muses-1.2/muses.swf?url=http://listen.181fm.com:8002&lang=auto&codec=mp3&tracking=true&volume=65&autoplay=true&buffering=5&skin=http://itnotes.in/RLC/swf/Radio/muses-1.2/simple-gray/ffmp3-simple-gray.xml&title=Vishara%20Designs')); 
loader.x=Xpos;
loader.y=Ypos;
addChild(loader);
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Radio Function
radio.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, RadioBtnClick);
function RadioBtnClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
removeChild(loader);
SoundMixer.stopAll(); //stop all sounds...
loader.load(new URLRequest('http://itnotes.in/RLC/swf/Radio/muses-1.2/muses.swf?url=http://listen.181fm.com:8002&lang=auto&codec=mp3&tracking=true&volume=65&autoplay=true&buffering=5&skin=http://itnotes.in/RLC/swf/Radio/muses-1.2/simple-gray/ffmp3-simple-gray.xml&title=Vishara%20Designs')); 
loader.x=Xpos;
loader.y=Ypos;
addChild(loader);
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//TV Function
tv.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, TvBtnClick);
function TvBtnClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
removeChild(loader);
SoundMixer.stopAll(); //stop all sounds...
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://avastarentertainment.com/avanced2avan/AVAncedPlayer_TX_DeSiRe_TGZ_MS_vww861102_181powerTop40_4_29_16rev11EpCc_SSER.swf"));
loader.x=Xpos;
loader.y=Ypos;
addChild(loader);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your codes don't have any problems, test your project's output on your browser {*in maximized window mode*}.

> Note:

1. The file 
   [AVAncedPlayer_TX_DeSiRe_TGZ_MS_vww861102_181powerTop40_4_29_16rev11EpCc_SSER.swf](http://avastarentertainment.com/avanced2avan/AVAncedPlayer_TX_DeSiRe_TGZ_MS_vww861102_181powerTop40_4_29_16rev11EpCc_SSER.swf)

doesn't work in another domain. so it must load within http://avastarentertainment.com/ 
domain (another contents required for loading this file, which are accessible only on that domain {*copyright*} )

Comment: Thank you Iman for your response Iman... I guess that makes sense... I will try to load an another swf.

Comment: @VishnuAnilkumar: Good luck.